# Do Web Workers have their own browser cache?

Tags: html, reactjs, image, caching

I am creating a web application (in react) that is intended to run on kiosks. This application shows product information along with images of the products.

There are 1000s of products, each with multiple images, but in this case I only care about the "feature image", and this is always 250x250px.

I have created a web worker to pre-fetch all of these images, and the code appears to be working. I can see in the network requests if I reload the page or rerun the worker the request is served from the disk cache.

However, when the same URL is used in  tag, it still loads from the network, which can be shown here (I blocked the url to see if the cache was working or not):

[image: image of blocked network request]

In the Web Worker I am doing this:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.open('GET', "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0585/6621/3830/products/85cc58608bf138a50036bcfe86a3a362.jpg?v=1645721232&width=250&height=250&crop=center", true);
xhr.send();
```

And for the image tag it's just this:

```
<img
alt=""
src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0585/6621/3830/products/85cc58608bf138a50036bcfe86a3a362.jpg?v=1645721232&width=250&height=250&crop=center"
onLoad={() => {
    setThumbnailState('loaded');
}}
onError={() => {
    setThumbnailState('error');
}}
/>
```

I had expected that the request would be served from the cache no matter where in the application it was loaded from, but instead I can see that everytime its loaded from an  tag its always loaded directly from the network.

I can also see that its now always being served from the disk cache when my web worker kicks in, so I know its still cached.